# Activity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java, android, deprecated

im trying to Create this android app
i have this note of uses or overrides a deprecated API
How can i Fix it ??
This is the code :

```
public class SplachScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

public static int Splash_time = 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splach_screen);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplachScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, Splash_time);

  }
}
```

Comment: can you show me xml code of activity_splach_screen?

Comment: Could you please provide complete error message? The code you provided looks valid.

Comment: @HussainAbbas <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplachScreen">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Logosplash"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: @MaxV thats the full error message